# How do I revert to normal keyboard?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

Im using Ubuntu 64-bit CLI and I must have pressed an odd combination of keys because now instead of normal letters etc I am getting symbols like this

[image: keyboard symbols screenshot]

Anyone know how to revert back to normal keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `reset` and press enter.